# Get Older Visual Studio Code Extension VSIX File

Tags: visual-studio-code, offline

I need an older version of an extension VSIX file (used for an offline installation), but the "Download Extension" button on the marketplace page only downloads the latest version:

[image]

How can I get older versions in the VSIX format?

Comment: look in the **Version History** tab, the last 5 versions are downloadable. Or clone the repo, checkout the requested version, build a vsix file

Comment: @rioV8 is there a way to see more than the last 5 versions without going to a github tag? It is not guaranteed that the tags/changelog posted is up to date.

Comment: the market place will not keep a lot of old versions